# Jint подключение DOM c#

Tags: c#

Есть проблема, есть код JavaScript который использует DOM, код парсится с веб страницы так что переписать его нету возможности, для обработки JavaScript используется Jint возможно ли к нему подключить DOM? Все написано на WPF.

Comment: А причём тут WPF?

Comment: Просто пометил.